# Using RCA to read voltage

Tags: voltage, analog, rca

I've connected an RCA cable to a device to read an analog voltage signal that's +/- 2.5V from what I can tell. The problem is that I need to somehow connect the other male RCA end with the computer in order to read the signal via program (LabVIEW to be specific), and I've connected a analog-to-digital converter (NI USB-6009) for that purpose.

Question: Is there an adapter that can make the male RCA into some kind of 2 or 3 wire that's pos/neg or pos/neg/gnd so that I can connect it to the converter? Or is it possible to strip the actual cable down (i.e. cut the RCA cable) and separate out the different components?

Comment: What? Your question isn't clear.  Stripping the cable isn't a good idea.

Comment: It is very easy to open up an RCA cable and get to the two leads. Usually they are even color coded to match the ends which is helpful when using several. Here is a photo of what you'll have in the end: http://i946.photobucket.com/albums/ad302/Jesserettele/crossfire%20new%20HU%20to%20stock%20amp/IMG_1729.jpg You may want to tin the ends of these with solder before you put them into your device so that they don't fray.

Answer (score 1):

According to the NI USB-6009 specs, it can be driven either with a floating signal source or a grounded single-ended source. An RCA connector provides a two-terminal connection, preferably with the exposed shell grounded. See p. 12 of the [manual](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/371303m.pdf) for a diagram, most likely RSE on the lower left.

This depends, of course on your signal source: is *it* floating or single-ended? Be careful of ground loops and voltage limit, so you don't fry the PC and ADC.

Answer (score 0):

This "adapter" should do. It certainly makes your RCA cable adapt to a 2+2 wire specification. After you've applied the "adapter", put some crimps on the ends. Some like to put sonder on the ends, but I avoid that as it is detrimental to proper contact, especially on higher voltages.

As for your specific of pos/neg/gnd on one of them, this becomes an issue, as RCA is a 2wire contact. What ground means in this setting can vary: It could be any shielding the cable might have, or it could be the negative lead.

[image: Universal cable adapter]